# Problem passing markdown template via gitlab projects api in a python script

Tags: python, markdown, gitlab-api

I am trying to use the gitlab projects api to edit multiple project MR templates. The problem is, that it only sends the first line of the markdown template.

While messing around with the script, I was toying with converting it to html when I found that it sent the whole template when converted to html.

I am probably missing something super simple but for the life of me, I cant figure out why it would be able to send the entire template in html but only send the first line of it natively in markdown.

I have been searching for a solution for a bit now so I apologize if my googlefu missed an obvious answer here.

Here is the script...

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import requests


gitlab_addr = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4"

# Insert your project IDs into the array below.
project_IDs = [xxxx, yyyy, zzzz]

# Insert your MR template info below.
with open('/.gitlab/merge_request_templates/DefaultMRTemplate.md', 'r') as file:
    MR_template = file.read()
    #print(MR_template)


def getArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='This tool updates the default template for a single '
        'or multiple program\'s MRs. \n\nYou will need to edit '
        'the script to input your MR template and projects IDs.'
        '\nYou will also need to pass in your API Token via '
        ' command line.\n\nYou want to see "200 OK" on the '
        ' command line as confirmation.',
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("token", type=str,
        help="API Token. Create one at User Settings / Access Tokens")
    return parser.parse_args()


def ChangeTemplate():
    token = getArgs().token
    headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": token, }

    for x in project_IDs:
        addr = f"{gitlab_addr}/projects/{x}/?merge_requests_template={MR_template}"

        response = requests.put(addr, headers=headers)

        # You want to see "200 OK" on the command line.
        print(response.status_code, response.reason)


def main():
    ChangeTemplate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is a sample template...

```
See guidance here:  https://example.com/Gitlab+MR+Guide

## Description

%% Put a description here %%

%% Add an issue link here %%

## Tests

%% Include test listing here %%

## Checklists

**Author Checklist**
- [ ] A: Did you fill out the description, add an issue link (in title or desc) and fill out the test section?
- [ ] A: Add a peer to the MR 

**Assignee 1 Checklist:**
- [ ] P: Verify the description field is filled out, issue link is included (in title or desc) and the test section is filled out
- [ ] P: Add a code owner to the MR 

**Assignee 2 (Code Owner) Checklist:**
- [ ] O: Verify the description field is filled out, issue link is included (in title or desc) and the test section is filled out
- [ ] O: Verify unit test coverage is at least 40% line coverage with a goal of 90%
```

problem output...

```
See guidance here:  https://example.com/Gitlab MR Guide
```

Comment: Try removing the query string from the URL and instead use the `data` keyword argument to `.put` to pass the data in the request body, which will automatically correctly encode the arguments as needed: `requests.put(addr, headers=headers, data={'merge_requests_template': MR_template})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data needs to be properly encoded in the request. Trying to format the literal contents of the file into the query string won't work here.

Use the `data` keyword argument to `requests.put`, which will pass the data in the request body (or use `params` to set query params). `requests` will handle the proper encoding of the data.

```py
addr = f"{gitlab_addr}/projects/{x}/"
payload = {'merge_requests_template': MR_template}
response = requests.put(addr, headers=headers, data=payload)
# or params=payload to use query string
```